# Gitlab CI/CD does not trigger automatically when merge request is created OR code changes are detected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci-trigger

We are currently using Gitlab CICD pipeline but it is not automatically triggered whenever the developer push some code changes OR when they create merge request. Is there any method to automatically trigger the pipeline once any merge request is created by the developers?

Waiting for your kind response.

Thanks

Currently we manually merge by clicking on merge and then pipeline is triggred. We want to automate this.

Comment: What does your **.gitlab-ci.yaml** look like? Also you can read through this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html It should help.

Comment: It would be impossible for us to say why it doesn't trigger if you don't show the CI file. Do you have some rules set up that only trigger on the default branch? again show your CI file. Is the end result you just want the job to trigger even on code push to feature branch or in merge request?

Comment: Sure, I'll post the sample file here soon, Actually when developers make some changes on their side(the microservices they are working on) they merge that code and a senior developer will approve it. Then they create a merge request through Asana, so we as a Devops check the merge request if any dependencies etc then click on the merge button so new change will be merged into develop/test etc branch, and then the pipeline is triggered. So here we want to automatically trigger the pipeline when we receive a merge request from developer.

Comment: @OlakunleAbiola thanks for your feedback and the link, btw this we can apply in the  free version of GitLab even if our organization size is greater 15 members?